# Creating a full text search on xml column

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I searched much in internet about "Creating a full text search on xml column". I found this link but this link does not work.
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=113478

EDITED:

```
create database test;
use test;
create table tbl_manuals
(
ID int not null,
xmlcontent xml not null,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([ID])
);

  -- Create fulltext catalog
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FTC_XML;
GO
-- Create fulltext index
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON dbo.tbl_manuals (xmlcontent LANGUAGE  1025) KEY INDEX PK_TestTable
ON FTC_XML;
GO

SELECT * FROM tbl_manuals WHERE FREETEXT(xmlcontent, 'apply', LANGUAGE 1033)
```

output is:

```
apply
applying
applies
applied
```

I also have these in tbl_manuals:

```
بود
بوده
بودان
بودن

SELECT * FROM tbl_manuals WHERE FREETEXT(xmlcontent, 'بودان', LANGUAGE 1025) or contains(xmlcontent, '"*بود*"', LANGUAGE 1025)
```

output is:

```
بود
بودان
```

Why?

Comment: See https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/  - the techniques shown should apply to XML columns, too, as far as I know.

Comment: I found aother link[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=6YEnCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=full+index+and+xml+column+in+sql&source=bl&ots=eFyIGpEvFL&sig=ds0CHG6Tz02LRBhfX2L1WRCaUJg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu4PTgusjNAhVDShQKHdpbAt84ChDoAQgrMAM#v=onepage&q=full%20index%20and%20xml%20column%20in%20sql&f=false) but I have error on key INDEX. I have ID column that is primery key and an xml column.

Comment: I edited my question. I saw difference between output of searching in a non xml column and an xml column for LANGUAGE 1025. For a non xml column, the output is complete but for an xml column, the output is not complete. Why?